# Inline button for clearing cache and reloading iframe with canvas background

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an `iframe` reloading with and inline button but cant get the `canvas` background image to reload with this. The restrictions for the framework I'm building in require all the actions to be inline which is where the problem is. I'm also not able to resolve this with no cache in the header of the page.

This is for embedding in an web application that has static text accepting html, js, python, and php but only if there are inline elements that do not require external files to work. I've tried several options for `history.go(0)` but can't seem to find the fix.

```
onclick="var ifr=document.getElementsByName('lc-drawing with-gui')[0]; ifr.src=ifr.src;history.go(0);">Refresh Image
```

I expect the `iframe`d canvas which is loaded with http://literallycanvas.com/ to refresh the background image when the button is used. What happens is the `iframe` reloads but the canvas background does not update when the image file is changed.

Comment: The onclick code in there is what is in the button to refresh the iframe titled 'lc-drawing with-gui'

Comment: I solved this by instead of using the canvas to load the image I loaded the canvas with a transparent background and then set the image in the div behind it. After that I used this little code to just refresh the image by cache busting.
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload()
{
img = document.getElementById("form_quoimg1_img");
img.src="img.png?rand_number=" + Math.random();
}
</script><input type=button onClick=reload(); value='Reload image'>